# What's the best way to make a Roslyn analyzer configurable?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm playing around with making an analyzer for Roslyn. The one I'm making is a diagnostic that finds methods that are too long. I'd like to make whatever is considered 'too long' configurable, preferably one configuration for an entire solution or project. What would be the best way to go about this?

The only option I have in mind is to search the assembly for a particular configuration attribute. This would require an attribute for each project in the solution. Also it requires the user of the diagnostic to reference a library specific to the diagnostic that defines this attribute.

Is this a good idea, and what are the other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass [additional files](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/DiagnosticAnalyzer/AnalyzerOptions.cs,7197d586b9314062) to the analyzers. These can then be reached from the analysis context. But this approach is not that developed yet in Roslyn. For example if the file changes, the analyzers are not notified about the change.

For an example you can check out the [SonarLint repository](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/blob/master/src/SonarAnalyzer.Common/Helpers/ParameterLoader.cs).

Also, keep an eye on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/6324), where the discussion is going on how parameters and data sharing should be done in the upcoming Roslyn version.

Comment: The SonarLint repository link is giving me a 404. It looks like they don't do this themselves anymore, or they have factored the ParameterLoader into a separate project.

Comment: Never mind... I found the [ParameterLoader](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonaranalyzer-dotnet/blob/master/src/SonarAnalyzer.Common/Helpers/ParameterLoader.cs) again.

Comment: @MichaelAlbertson I edited the new hyperlink into the answer for you! Thanks for tracking it down!!